# Итерация и рекурсия в Oracle

Tags: база-данных, oracle, рекурсия

Доброе время суток! Есть некая таблица tb:

```
  ID  |  PARENT_ID  |  LEV
---------------------------
10165  |10167      |0
10167  |10163      |0
10163  |10000      |2
10000  |null       |2
```

Стоит задача для всех ID найти ближайший PARENT_ID c LEV=2.
Уровень вложенности может быть любым. Например для ID=10165 это будет 10163. 
Значение для одного id можно найти рекурсивным запросом:

```
select ID from tb where LEV='2'
start with ID='10165' connect by ID = prior PARENT_ID and rownum=1;
```

Но нужно одним запросом найти для всех ID и вывести в новую таблицу:
ID | PARENT_LEV2_ID
Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Почитайте про хранимые процедуры.

Comment: А для ID 10163 какой ближайший с lev=2 он сам или 10000 ?

Comment: Mike, для ID=10163 ближайшим является он сам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заходим с другой стороны, от всех записей с lev=2 идем ко всем дочерним. при этом уровень вложенности connect by (`level`) - это расстояние от данного корня до конкретного дочернего элемента. Нам надо взять для каждого дочернего элемента тот путь по которому путь минимален. Нумеруем записи по уровню и берем первые.

```
select ID, root
  from (
        select ID,connect_by_root(id) root,
               row_number() over(partition by id order by level) rn
          from tb
         start with lev=2
       connect by PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID
  )
 where rn=1
```